# How to show and hide select box field in adminhtml form in backend

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, grid, jquery, adminform

[image: By default, Footer group select box should not be displayed]

[image: And when clicked on position select box footer it should display Footer group select box]

By default, Footer group select box  should not be displayed.
 And when clicked on position select box footer it should display Footer group select box

```
$Lastfield =  $fieldset->addField(
            'position',
            'select',
            [
                'label' => __('Position'),
                'title' => __('Position'),
                'name' => 'position',
                'onchange'  => 'onchangeStyleShow()',
                'options' => 
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]
        );

         $fieldset->addField(
            'footer_group',
            'select',
            [
                'title' => __('Footer group'),
                'label' => __('Footer group'),
                'name' => 'footer_group',   
                'values' => $value,
                'disabled' => $isElementDisabled
            ]  
        );
        $Lastfield->setAfterElementHtml(
            '<script>
             function onchangeStyleShow(){
                $("footer_group").toggle()
                }
            </script>'
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You forget to set id in **onchangeStyleShow**() function. Please replace the below code :

```
$Lastfield->setAfterElementHtml(
            '<script>
             function onchangeStyleShow(){
                $("#footer_group").toggle();
                }
            </script>'
    );
```